# Can this O(n) Matrix Rotation algorithm be done in place and remain O(n)?

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

**Question:**

Can the algorithm posted below be adjusted to use the same array (which represents a 2D matrix) for a clockwise rotation instead of using a second array and still remain at O(n) complexity?

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixRotation {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dimension = 5;

    int[] array = generate(dimension);
    print(array, dimension);

    int[] clockwise = clockwise(array, dimension);
    print(clockwise, dimension);
  }

  //Generate a matrix with random values
  private static int[] generate(int dimension) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[dimension * dimension];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
    return array;
  }

  //Rotates the matrix clockwise by calculating where the value's position should be after the rotation
  private static int[] clockwise(int[] array, int dimension) {
    int[] rotated = new int[array.length];
    int baseCount = dimension;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      int remainder = i % dimension;

      if(remainder == 0)
        baseCount--;

      int position = baseCount + (dimension * remainder);

      //I suspect I can do some kinda swapping functionality here but am stumped

      rotated[position] = array[i];
    }

    return rotated;
  }

  //Used to display the matrix
  private static void print(int[] array, int dimension) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(i % dimension == 0) 
        System.out.println();
      System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
1 7 4 1 4 
2 3 5 2 9 
4 3 9 3 1 
5 8 7 5 6 
3 3 7 2 5 

3 5 4 2 1 
3 8 3 3 7 
7 7 9 5 4 
2 5 3 2 1 
5 6 1 9 4
```

**Background:**

I was reading a question the other day about matrix rotations represented in a 1D array and decided to take swing at it. I managed to successfully create a rotation algorithm by calculating the next position of the value after the rotation. Currently I'm trying to determine if there's a way to keep it as O(n) while reducing the space used by keeping it inside the same array. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution! I wasn't able to determine how to make it work with the posted algorithm, but once I started designing it from scratch with rotation swapping from the start I found a solution in the same complexity (essentially). I designed it with the idea of working from the outside to the inside via "onion layers" by finding the corners of each layer and then rotating them and their relative directional adjacent. Something like:

```
    ↓                      ↓                     ↓
    5 5 8 2 1 ←          7 5 8 2 5           7 2 8 2 5  
    9 4 8 2 3            9 4 8 2 3 ←         9 4 8 2 5 
    6 3 7 5 4            6 3 7 5 4         → 6 3 7 5 4 ←       Ect...
    2 6 4 2 7          → 2 6 4 2 7           5 6 4 2 7 
  → 7 0 7 5 5            5 0 7 5 1           5 0 7 3 1 
            ↑                  ↑                 ↑
```

For each layer.

**Code:**

```
  private static int[] clockwise2(int[] array, int dimension) {
    int layers = dimension / 2; //Total layers of the onion
    //Loop through the layers
    for (int i = 0; i < layers; i++) {
      int layerWidth = dimension - 2 * i; //Current layer width

      int topStart = i + dimension * i; //Top left corner
      int rightStart = topStart + (layerWidth - 1); //Top right corner
      int bottomStart = (array.length - 1) - topStart; //Bottom right corner
      int leftStart = bottomStart - (layerWidth - 1); //Bottom left corner

      //Loop values in current layer
      for (int j = 0; j < layerWidth - 1; j++) {
        int topIndex = topStart + j; //Move right
        int rightIndex = rightStart + dimension * j; //Move down
        int bottomIndex = bottomStart - j; //Move left
        int leftIndex = leftStart - dimension * j; //Move up

        //Swap the values in a circular direction
        int temp = array[topIndex];
        array[topIndex] = array[leftIndex];
        array[leftIndex] = array[bottomIndex];
        array[bottomIndex] = array[rightIndex];
        array[rightIndex] = temp;
      }
    }

    return array;
  }
```